# Can I take the p-value from a probability table for a modified z-score, just like a z-score?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, p-value, z-score

I have a question regarding the modified Z-score, can I use this score in a Z-probability table, i.e. the p-value from a modified z-score?

where:

**z-score = (xi - μ)/σ**
(the z-score probability can be obtained from [links](https://statisticsbyjim.com/hypothesis-testing/z-table))

**modified z-score = 0.6745(xi - median(x))/median(|xi-median(x)|)**
i can use **modified z-score** to get its probability from the same table

Comment: Please explain what a "modified z-score" is and what probability model you are using.

Comment: thanks @whuber, I'll try to be clear. It is considered that `z-score = (xi - μ)/σ`. Then from the z-score we can obtain the probability according to the probability table [link](https://statisticsbyjim.com/hypothesis-testing/z-table), i.e., p-value from the z-score by looking at the table. Now a `modified z-score = 0.6745(xi - median(x)) / median(|xi-median(x)|)`, where `median(x)`: is the mean of the data set, so can I do this? Get p-value using `modified z-score` by looking at the `same probability table`.

Comment: p-values are associated to statistical tests, which require null hypothesis and test statistic to be defined. You don't define any such thing, so what you call p-value doesn't seem to be a p-value.

Comment: "The probability" you mention is supposed to be a probability of what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is worth noting that, with modern computers, we never (ever) have to use z-scores for sample statistics instead of t-scores even for large sample sizes, for which these two scores are quite close.
The z-score is used only when one *knows* the **true** standard deviation (or variance) of the **random variable** (not of the sample), which happens either if one is God or when one generates the random sample on a computer.
**If the random variable is normally distributed**, empirically (in a Monte Carlo simulation) you may approximate (and compare it with what you might get in the z-score or t-score table) that *p*-value with the following function in [R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(programming_language)).

```r
modified_t_score_p_value <- function(modified_t_score, sample_size, simulation_size) {
    coef <- qnorm(0.75)
    sample <- matrix(rnorm(sample_size * simulation_size), nrow=simulation_size)
    medians <- apply(sample, 1, median)
    diff <- sample - medians
    sample <- coef * diff / median(abs(diff))
    print(paste0('p-value of modified sample z-score: ', mean(modified_t_score > sample)))
    print(paste0('p-value of real t-score: ', pt(modified_t_score, sample_size-1)))
    print(paste0('p-value of real z-score: ', pnorm(modified_t_score)))
}
modified_t_score_p_value(-2.0, 10, 100000)
```

Output

```
[1] "p-value of modified sample z-score: 0.039845"
[1] "p-value of real t-score: 0.0382764118853505"
[1] "p-value of real z-score: 0.0227501319481792"
```